# URL rewriting .htaccess help needed

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Assume I have two domain names example1.com and example2.com. I forwarded example1.com to example2.com using the domain forwarding on hosting panel. It works fine but when I go to example1.com/sub it just shows example2.com as the URL. I want it to show example2.com/sub. I tried URL rewriting but no luck so far. It just keep loading and shows nothing. Am I missing something ?

This the rule I used.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}   !^example1.com$         [NC]
RewriteRule   (.*)           http://www.example2.com/$1  [R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that you've cleared your browser's cache. If it's a 301 redirect your browser will cache the redirect. Then make sure to turn **off** your hosting panel's forwarding.

Other than that, your rule should work fine, assuming it's at the top of the htaccess file in example1.com's document root.

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer. I removed the forwarding from domain registrar and htaccess file is in example1.com's document root. I also cleared the cache, and now it is showing a 404 not found error.

Comment: @doxteez is it no longer redirecting?

Comment: No its just showing a "404 Not Found" error when visited to the site.

Answer (score 0):

In RewriteCond rule you use **!**, which mean negate the result of the condition.